# java.awt.Graphics : abstract methods are called?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Abstract methods in java, like `clearRect`, `getColor` in the `java.awt.Graphics` class, should not have any method body. Then how come they could be invoked, like, inside the `paint(Graphics g)` method of class `javax.swing.JPanel`? When I did not suspect `Graphics` to be an abstract class, I had gathered that the `paint` method is invoked in the constructor of `JPanel` class, roughly in this way:

```
this.setGraphics(new Graphics());
paint(this.getGraphics());
```

But as it turns out, `setGraphics` is a non-existent method in class `JPanel`, but `getGraphics` exists. But then even how the `Graphics` component is set up for `JPanel`?

As for the main question, is there a non-abstract class extending `Graphics`, an instance of which was to go as a parameter of `paint` method? Then they could define it as a `Graphics` data type, while still filling in abstract method details, right?

Comment: Yes. `SunGraphics2D`.